# Как сделать тень с трех сторон?

Tags: html, css

есть тень  box-shadow: 0px 15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)

но оно задается со всех четырех сторон

нужно убрать её снизу  ( а по другим сторонам оставить)

Comment: пожалуйста, не надо плодить [дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1443165/178576)

Comment: замени 15px на -15px

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin почему же дубликат? Ответа в оригинальном вопросе нет, а тут ещё и более понятная формулировка, я бы сказал что это отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score -1):

```css
#el {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7) 0 -2px 4px;
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="el"></div>
```

Всё делаем по такой формуле чтобы тень снизу всегда не была бы видна:

`box-shadow: ЦВЕТ 0 -(РАЗМЫТЫЕ_ТЕНИ ÷ 2) РАЗМЫТЫЕ_ТЕНИ;`

То есть в вашем случае это должно быть так:

`box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0 -15px 30px;`

(Сделал цвет другой и менее прозрачным чтобы лучше было видно)

```css
#el {
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0 -15px 30px;
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="el"></div>
```

Answer (score -4):

[Желаю посмотреть](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)

```
box-shadow: 0px -5px 5px 5px #888888;
```